# Null foreign Key or table join

Tags: mysql

I have a user profile table.

```
id int (pk)
user_name varchar(50)
email_address varchar(100)
relationship_status tinyint(1)(FK)
```

I then have a relationship table. Relationship is optional field in user profile table. Is it best practice to do a null join if relationship_status is not selected or a table between relationship and user_profile.

This is simple example but I would ultimately end up with multiple tables in between if a join was optional. This might make for too many joins. However I have read can run into issues with null joins and not best practice.

Comment: and what exactly is your question ?

Comment: null join best or table in between i.e. user_relationship with user_id and relationship_id

Comment: Instead of introducing a new table, why cant you just make user_id as FK for relationship table. So `relationship` table also will have user_id and `relationship_status` will be moved out of user table to relationship table itself.

Comment: relationship_status is a list of statuses i.e. single, in a relationship etc

Comment: its either three tables or two with null join as far as i can see

Comment: Perhaps use an enum? Surely the values won't change much, unless you reserve the right to add colorful new statuses such as "humping my pony and loving it!"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relationship between the tables. If it's a one-to-many or a many-to-many.  If each user can have one and only one relationship status then do "null join" if each user can have multiple relationships than do a "table in between"

**Example of a one-to-many relationship:**

```
User Table
- id
- name
- relationship_id

Relationship Table
- id
- type
```

In this instance Relationship Table would have data like "user", "admin", etc and a user can only be a "user" OR an "admin" but not both.  (In this particular case sometimes I will have the Relationship table's id column would be a string like "user" or "admin" that way you don't have to do a join on it, you always have it in the user table).

**Example of a many-to-many relationship:**

```
User Table
- id
- name

Relationship Table
- id
- type

User Relationship Table
- user_id
- relationship_id
```

In this case a user can have multiple relationships. The relationship table would have data like "editor", "reviewer", "copywriter", "admin", etc. and each user can be any combination of those (i.e., user 1 can be an editor AND a copywriter).